# npm install error, is node-gyp mojave problem?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I can't resolve this error !! I'm getting crazy:

Here is the error:

```
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "/path/to/python27/python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:149:21)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.3.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/federicofrydman/Desktop/glamitGitHub/front-quiz/node_modules/fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v12.3.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-gyp exited with code: 1
```

This was suggested:

> Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
>   would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
>   build environment--
>   Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
>   Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
>   RHEL users please run: `yum install gcc-c++` and `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'` 
>   Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
>   sh: nodejs: command not found
>   npm WARN ts-pnp@1.1.2 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

```
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! fibers@3.1.1 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@3.1.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/federicofrydman/.npm/_logs/2019-07-02T03_47_12_405Z-debug.log
```

Using the following tools:

1.MOJAVE 10.14.5

2.XCODE 10.2.1

3.PYTHON 2.7

Comment: Please describe your problem more clearly, please use space between paragraph. use format text to error and source code. so others read easily and  can help you.

Comment: same happens to me, i tried different node versions,  but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Issue seems to be with fibers@3.1.1 which is not supported in node version 12.

Fix it by removing my latest nodejs, 12.3.1, and installing the previous stable version of 11.

https://nodejs.org/download/release/v11.15.0/